# Hashing functions with special characters?

Tags: hash, sha1

My application requires database to store username and password. To hash password I am looking for SHA 1 algorithm. Basically I need few special characters such as . , ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) along with A-Z , a-z, 0-9 etc in my hash. 

Any way to get them?

looking for php or javascript implementation.

Comment: For which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

It's output is just binary data. Encode it however you wish.

Comment: Can you give me any link of encoder example in java script for this purpose. Looking for a github link.